# how to write unit test for method that sshs into another machine?

Tags: testing, junit

I want to write unit test for a code that actually ssh  into another machine and runs command. I am lost as to how to go about attacking this problem.

The code basically runs a few commands(`copy`, `grep`, `awk`) on remote machine. How can I write test without having access to the remote machine. How do I emulate the remote machine environment?

*Considerations:*
- Assume that the machine where unit test runs doesn't have access to remote server where the ssh commands need to run.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't actually test the whole process of setting up a connection, running tasks, and testing the results (acceptance testing).

I would suggest breaking it up into two pieces:

1. **The first half where you expect to make a connection and the commands you wish to run.** Here you will just be testing that the methods you have for establishing the connection have the correct output you expect. Like, for example, testing that calling `connect` formulates the correct shell command string.
2. **The second part is to *simulate* a response from running `grep` (for example).** This is where you'd hand your code what you expect the other machine to send back to you and make sure that your code does what you'd expect with that particular response. Another example could be when you get `2017-1-17  The missiles launched` as a response, you test that your code saved a date and a status (obviously I have no idea what your application is, it's just an example)

This is how I would do it, but I'm sure others will give you good examples on how to test the full stack in one giant test. I think my way is a little more stable and modular making it easier to add more tests in the future.

Comment: Connect, running command everything is part of the method (for eg. public void runCmd();) in that case how do I go about it?
all other methods are private.

Comment: It sounds like you need to separate your concerns. If everything you're doing (connecting, running scripts, parsing responses, etc) lives in one class, you should consider breaking your class into several classes that each have a responsibility. You should, then, be able to test your individual parts/actions.

Answer (score 0):

you have at least the following options:

1. split your method into several distinct methods (connection and execute) and test the 'execute' part locally
2. make your test starts prepared docker container before running the command and have your command parameterized with url. after test(s), docker container should be stopped/deleted